# Getting an error when I use read.xls function of gdata package in R

Tags: r, excel, rstudio, gdata

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  no lines available in input
```

This is the error in the console. But I haven't used read.table? Is it an internal reference?

Answer (score 0):

You can view the code by typing `read.xls` or in RStudio, `View(read.xls)`.

`gdata::read.xls` works by first converting the Excel file to a tab or comma-delimited file. It then uses either `read.delim` or `read.csv` to read the data. Both of those functions are wrappers to `read.table`.

So yes: the function is using `read.table` internally.

Your next problem is to figure out why the conversion results in a file with no lines. It may be better to use a more modern solution such as the `readxl` package, or explore the Excel import interactively in RStudio.